# Performing pairwise regression analysis between matrices in two lists

Tags: r

Consider, i have two matrices, one with response, one with predictor variables, and i calculate distance matrices for each of those variables:

```
resp <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(6*6,mean=1000,sd=100), 6, 6)) 
pred <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(6*6,mean=1000,sd=100), 6, 6))
colnames(resp) <- paste("Resp_",letters[1:6],sep="")
colnames(pred) <- paste("Pred_",LETTERS[1:6],sep="")

#calculate distance matrices for each variable per site
Z <- lapply(resp, function(x) dist(x))
A <- lapply(pred, function(x) dist(x))
```

I want to perform mantel statistics for every pair of matrices between A and Z:

```
library(vegan)
res1 <- mantel(Z[[1]], A[[1]], method="spearman", perm=999)
res2 <- mantel(Z[[2]], A[[1]], method="spearman", perm=999)
```

or broadly put

```
res(i,j) <- mantel(Z[[1:i]], A[[1:j]], method="spearman", perm=999)
```

I am interested in retrieving the r and p-values as in `res1[[3]]` and res1`[[4]]`, possibly in a matrix, just like

```
cor(resp, pred)
```

How can i do this in a loop?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
r <- p <- matrix(NA, 6, 6)

colnames(r) <- colnames(p) <- names(A)
rownames(r) <- rownames(p) <- names(Z)

for (i in 1:6) {
  for (j in 1:6) {
    m <- mantel(Z[[i]], A[[j]], method="spearman", perm=999)
    r[i, j] <- m$statistic
    p[i, j] <- m$signif 
  }
}
```